# How to get the port numbers?

Tags: 16.04, usb, camera, opencv

My Setup consists of 3 cameras attached to [USB hub](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Startech-com-10-Port-Industrial-Usb-3-0-Hub-Esd-And-Surge-Protection-Din-/232371020158). And the usb hub is connected to the computer (USB 3.0).

I am trying to capture video from each of these camera and in order to do it I need to run [cv2.VideoCapture(device)](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) and need to get the port numbers. I google but haven't found a solution. How can i get the port number of each cameras ?

Answer (score 2):

"Port numbers" aren't used in Linux, "device names" are.

First, disconnect all 3 cameras.

Then, in a terminal window:

```
journalctl --follow
```

Then connect your cameras, and watch the system's logging.

Comment: +1 first time I noticed someone using `--follow` argument.

Comment: @https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix The `journalctl --follow` is So Useful that I have it running in a terminal window all the time. If my system misbehaves, the logs are right there.

Comment: bc kernel: usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd

May 23 19:49:01 bc kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=041e, idProduct=4095

May 23 19:49:01 bc kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2

May 23 19:49:01 bc kernel: usb 1-2: Product: Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770

May 23 19:49:01 bc kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Creative Technology Ltd.

May 23 19:49:01 bc kernel: usb 1-2: SerialNumber:  

May 23 19:49:01 bc kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770 (041e:4095)

What is my device name ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you will find your video cameras as `/dev/video?`, where `?` is a number starting at `0`.

If you need to reference a special camera and the `/dev/video?` devices are switching places or otherwise changing numbers, you should have a look at `/dev/v4l/`. You will find a structure there with symlinks to the video devices by device path or by id.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you.  I was trying to access all the USB camera at the same time(all connected to single USB 3.0 hub). Because of the bandwidth is issue, i was only able to access single camera at a time.

Comment: I am using usb-creative cameras. When i plugged in the TWO cameras, i noticed a file was created in  /dev/v41/by-id  --> "usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd._Live_CamSync_HD_VF0770-video-index0" and two files were created in /dev/v41/by-path --> "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:6:1.0-video-index0", "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:8:1.0-video-index0".    The default index for laptop inbuilt cam is '0'. Can explain how can i determine which of my attached camera are  indexed 1,2. So that i can make sure that all the images obtained from all the camera are saved in different folders in the code.

Comment: I think i figure it. 
Get the properties of all the files present in '/dev/v4l/by-path'  using subprocess.check_out  from there on we can find the linked target of the files.